# Calculating entropy of adjacency matrix using eigenvalue decomposition?

Tags: entropy, eigenvalues, taylor-series

How to calculate entropy using the eigenvalues when the eigenvalues are negative?

[Is there a simple relation between the entropy of a matrix and its characteristic polynomial?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102569/is-there-a-simple-relation-between-the-entropy-of-a-matrix-and-its-characteristic)

Comment: How do you define it?

Comment: the eigenvaluesof the matrix  $H$ have to be real, positive and sum to unity, otherwise the entropy makes no sense.